# count($arr) echos "1" but evaluates 0 inside "if" condition

Tags: php

I have an array that has 1 row, and count() on that array returns 1. But in next block of code, the count evaluates as 0 and the script dies. Any idea what's going on here?

```
// Array below is returned from another function as $arr_values
Array 
(
    [80000018-1302638711] => Array
        (
            [Logistics] => -1028.46
            [Sales & Marketing Expenses] => -400.00
            [Taxes & Duties] => -10171.48
        )

)    

echo count($arr_values); // returns '1'  

if(count($arr_values == 0)){   // We just demonstrated this is equal to '1'...
  return false;                // ... but this line still executes. WAT?
}
```

This is probably something simple. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Try `if(count($arr_values) == 0)`

Comment: Duh! It works. Submit this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I recommend turning on error reporting so that you are not essentially programming in a dark room without a monitor

Comment: I think you need to read this  link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552323/php-does-if-countarray-and-if-array-mean-the-same-thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your statement says

```
count($arr_values == 0)
```

which says count(boolean)

which says 0 as its not an array

you need to say `count($arr_values) == 0`

Comment: `count(false)` returns 1.